# I can't copy files to my memory card

Tags: 11.10, permissions, sd-card

I can't copy files to my memory card.

When i copy there is a error message and it says read-only file system.

But, i can copy file from the card.Can any one please help me.

I am using ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: I think "Ubuntu 11.10" has little relevance, I have 13.10 and the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think memory is locked on its adapter else formatting the memory would repair it

Comment: what works? I have the same problem and this answer tells me nothing. I can use GParted to format the device, and play with it's partition, GParted never complains. But Nautilus whines about the device being read-only when I copy files unto it... yup.

Answer (score 0):

If these information by wu-lee that can be helpful to you:

"Firstly, make sure the memory card hasn't got the "lock" tab engaged! This is a plastic sliding thing on the side of the card. Sometimes it is loose enough that pushing the card into the slot engages it. To allow writing, the tab should be pushed into the forward position, nearest the contacts.

Now make sure you have write permissions for the device. The memory card device is `/dev/mmcblk0` (other devices will be different), so try this:

```
$ ls -l /dev/mmcblk0
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 179, 0 2010-08-04 10:35 /dev/mmcblk0
```

This shows it's readable and writable (rw) by the root user, and the disk group. I'm not root, so am I in the disk group?

```
$ groups
nick adm dialout cdrom plugdev lpadmin admin sambashare
```

Nope. So how do I become a member? You can set your user's group membership in Applications->settings->sytem settings->advanced->user management (KDE) or in System->Admin->Users and Groups (Gnome). Or you can do it with the command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G disk $USER
```

Where `$USER` is your user name.

Now check it worked - "disk" should be listed in your group membership, like this:

```
$ groups
nick adm disk dialout cdrom plugdev lpadmin admin sambashare
```

Typically group membership won't get updated until you open a new log-in shell or start a new session. So you may need to log off and on again, or open a login shell like this:

```
$ su - $USER -c bash
```

Now, as a member of the "disk" group, you should have write access to the memory card.

[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1470018&page=2)

Comment: it is not working yet..........

Comment: What about a chmod 777 to the directory where the SD Card is mounted?

Comment: Please update your question and tell us what file system is on the SD card and permissions of the mount point (should be in /media) . A file system also gets mounted ro when there is a problem, so unmount the sd and try running fsck.